# Why is my background image refusing to show up?

Tags: html, css

I can't get a background image to show up in the body of my file. Here is the html-

```
<body>
<div class="test">
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="query" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css

```
#test{
background-image:     url("https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/background-wallpapers-32_NRz0mTd.jpg");
}
```

I initially tried a local image and that didn't work so I tried a different image from the web. It is a php document not sure if that matters or not.

Comment: `class="test"` -> `.test { ... }`, or change `class="test"` to `id="test"`

Comment: if you are using chrome, try to inspect the code and see if there is any error message. If there is, post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class attribute is not interchange-able with id attribute.

Your CSS currently says `#test`, meaning look for an id named "test". `#` symbol refers to id.

But you currently have no `<div id="test"`, what you are using is `<div class="test"`.

### Recommendation

In your HTML, change it to `<div id="test"`

Comment: That was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your style sheet is referencing an ID `#test`. You have declared your div to be of the class test. So like @Taig says you need to change one or the other to match.

```
.test{
background-image: url("https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/background-wallpapers-32_NRz0mTd.jpg");
}
```

in css `#value` references an ID, `.value` references a class.

Answer (score 1):

When setting a div background with CSS, you need to specify a width and a height. For example, an image with 380x380px:

```
#test{
    background-image:     url("https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/background-wallpapers-32_NRz0mTd.jpg");
    width:380px;
    height:380px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your div id / class must be the same as on your stylesheet.

So if your div is an id it must be `#test {}` on the stylesheet, and if it is class it must be `.test {}.`

But you can not just pick and make it into class or id. A class must be used more then once and can be bind to other tags.

An id is bind once to a tag.

http://www.html5-tutorials.org/html-basics/id-and-class/